# ng-repeat array object inside array object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my index.html file we use two ng-repeat file to get data from data.json .

In this approach each data created repeated DOM.

How to use single ng-repeat instead of double ng-repeat in my index.html .

```
<div ng-repeat="x in userdata">
      <item data="y" ng-repeat="y in x.content"></item>
    </div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/uGRmYSv90kbjFzx9qmkI?p=preview

Comment: how exactly you want the output to be?

Comment: I want to get each object in single ng-repeat but my code get each results use one ng-repeat

Comment: @jos: I want to use single ng-repeat to get same results

Comment: @CodeMan You need to prepare your data, instead of `userdata` it should a concatenation of all `content` array imo

Comment: @codeMan your content array can be conveted to a map where name is the key and content as the value. add this map to array and repeat it

Comment: @jos can u ls provide snippet of code ,  i'm not understanding

Comment: please check this https://plnkr.co/edit/cM9Fcqy5x0XU3SGH85NY?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested  angular for each in js,so u can use single ng-repeat using final scope

```
Database.getDatabase().success(function(data){
      $scope.userdata=data.document;
       $scope.sample = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.userdata, function(content) {
    angular.forEach(content.content, function(content) {
      $scope.sample.push(content);
    })
  })

}).error(function(){
});
```

now u can loop with sample as

```
<div ng-repeat="x in sample">
     {{x.content}}
    </div>
```

[updated with foreach](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJGOM98n8bMNPTMWEAKj?p=preview)

Comment: i have only two "content" array objects avilable in "document" so i need to repeat two times only .Each ng-repeat i need to get all the details liks "content" and "name"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `$scope.userdata = data.document` you could do:

```
$scope.userdata = data.document.reduce(function(a, b) { 
    return a.concat(b.content);
}, []);
```

This will place all the `content` in the same array. and use it exactly how you have commented in your plunker

```
<item data="x" ng-repeat="x in userdata"></item>
```

Here's an update on your [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EqzJuKpArY7JmYjI3FNa?p=preview)

Comment: slim one compare to  mine

Answer (score 0):

create a map with the contents and add as another object to the documents

```
var createMap = function(list) {
   var map = {};
   for(var i =0;i <list.length ; i++) {
     map[list[i].name] = list[i].content;
  }
   return map;
 };
    Database.getDatabase().success(function(data){
      for(var i =0;i <data.document.length ; i++) {
        data.document[i]['userdata'] = createMap(data.document[i].content);
      }
      $scope.userdata=data.document;
      console.log($scope.userdata);
}).error(function(){
});
```

[plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cM9Fcqy5x0XU3SGH85NY?p=preview)